# mvvmcross binding on switch fails on release

Tags: binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a weird bug in my MVVMCross app.

Considering the following scenario:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/activatedSwitch"
    local:MvxBind="Checked IsActive" />
```

- Compile version: level 14
- Minimum version:  level 14
- Target version:  level 14
- Linking: Sdk Assemblies Only
- Android Phone version is 4.1.2.

When I run the app in **Debug** mode, all is ok.

But when I run it in **Release**, the binding to the Checked property failed with the following error:

> E/MvxBind (11670):   12,70 View type not found - Switch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since MvvmCross uses reflection to perform databinding, the linker is not seeing the `Checked` property and is not including it in your binary. There is a file name `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` that you can edit to add a reference to this property.

Something like:

```
public void Include(Switch @switch)
{
    @switch.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => @switch.Checked = !@switch.Checked;
}
```

Comment: why do we need @ sign in the param?

Comment: Because "switch" is a reserved keyword in C# (switch/case). The @ allows you to use reserved keywords as an identifier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of MVVMCross has this issue addressed. The below code is only enough.
**Note**:- MvvmCross 7.0. I am using.  But I suspect this could be addressed in before releases.

```
local:MvxBind="Checked IsActive"
```

Comment: Well, the solution I work on is on MvvmCross 7.1.2 and I had to use the LinkerPleaseInclude trick. Otherwise it stays broken in Release mode.